# Move a new file to a specific folder! google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have written a short script that should work, however I have got an error coming back and I can not figure out why.

The error is "Exception: The parameters (DriveApp.File) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.moveTo.
NewSheets   "

my script is below, thanks in advance to anyone who can see the error.

```
    function NewSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName('URL');

  for(i=1;i<ss1.getLastRow();i++){
    var s1 = ss1.getRange(i+1,6).getValue()
    var folder = DriveApp.getFileById('1W5LeSrijdfFvgqZQfKEhrK7YOziHL322');
    var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create('STSOR - '+s1)
    var id = newSS.getId()
    DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder);
    var paste = ss.getSheetByName(s1).copyTo(newSS).setName('STSOR - '+s1)
    ss1.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(id)

  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mving your file to another file. You should be using `getFolderById()` on this line:

```js
var folder = DriveApp.getFileById('1W5LeSrijdfFvgqZQfKEhrK7YOziHL322');
```

You code also has other problems. There is no reason to get the folder on every iteration of the loop. And you should also move your `getRange()` and other API calls outside the loop. Read through the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) for better quality code.

Comment: Thank you, unsure how I missed that,

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
function NewSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('URL');
  const fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 6, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let newss = SpreadsheetApp.create('STSOR - ' + r[0]);
    let id = newss.getId();
    DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(fldr);
    ss.getSheetByName(r[0]).copyTo(newss).setName('STSOR - ' + r[0]);
    sh.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(id);
  });
}
```